# Unable to call restful webservice from JS Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I wanted to call a RESTful webservice from mobilefirst 8.0 Javascript Adapter, but the thing is when I am calling it from Javascript Adapter its getting failed but when I am calling the same service from Java Adapter its getting executed successfully. Following is the code:

**JS Adapter Code (Not Working)**

```
function addStatus(requestData){
        var input = {
                method              : 'put',
                returnedContentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                path                : "cli/version/addStatus?version=1&status=APPROVED&UCD_SESSION_KEY=1",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization":"Basic " + requestData.authHeader,
                    "Accept" : "application/json",
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                    "Connection", "keep-alive"
                }
        };

        var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
        return response;
}
```

In the response, I am getting **status code as 302**.

**Java Adapter Code (Working)**

```
            String pageUrl ="https://my.server.url:port/cli/version/addStatus?version=1&status=APPROVED&UCD_SESSION_KEY=1";
            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPut httpGet = new HttpPut(pageUrl);
            String credential = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes());
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credential);
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpGet.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

I am not getting any error and I am able to see the changes done by this service. AM I missing something in making the **input** inside my JS Adapter?

Comment: Looks like the backend service is returning a "redirect" return code, can u paste the complete response? does it also hv a uRI to redirect to ?

Comment: No. It does not have a URI to redirect to. The same URL is working when I am invoking it from Java Adapter. I pasted the code snippet in the question.

Comment: Have you checked in swagger ? Also print input value to check it's correct or not.

Comment: Yes I verified that, Input values are correct. I am using consumer edition, swagger is not there.

Comment: Can you try sending the paramters using "setQueryParameter" option rather than in the url in your javascript adapter?

Comment: @Keerthi...I suppose you are referring while sending the request to the adapter I should use setQueryParameter.  FYI  that's how I am sending the query param from client code before invoking the MFP Adapter procedure:

<code>dataRequest.setQueryParameter("params", `[${jsonToStingData}]`);</code>

Comment: @PrerakTiwari, please capture network traffic at the MFP server. This will tell us what came in and went to the backend .And what backend responded.